# Edit tag wiki being redirect with no notification as to why

Tags: bug, tags, tag-wiki

When trying to edit a tag wiki with 5 or more edits waiting for review I am automatically redirected to the tag's info page without being told why.

I tried to make an edit to a tag wiki by clicking "Improve tag info".

[image: Improve tag info]

I can see that the link is to `https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/1234` but I am instead taken to the tag's info page at `https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mdi/info`.

It looks like I am being redirected

[image: redirect header]

But there is no clear indication as to why the redirect is happening.

---

After a while I did manage to figure out who to reproduce the problem.

This happens for all tags when

- User is below 2000 rep
- User has 5 or more pending edits waiting for review

Ideally there should be some indication that the user is not able to make any more edits. A redirect is very confusing. Other places on the site a little red box pops up saying "You have too many edits waiting for review". Something like that here would be helpful.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic Wow, then it is the reason! I think it would deserve even a bug report on the meta SE. However, to reproduce it, you have to edit 5 posts...

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic Last time I've did massive edits, I've faced quite [different](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2340/50837) problems, but not yours. I think it is a very hardly reproducible problem. I've got simply an error message as I clicked "submit".