# Should my closed meta post about a bug be reopened?

Tags: support, reopen-closed

I posted [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368188/9614249) on Meta about some weird behavior I encountered on the main site.

Initially I didn't know what was causing the problem and the question was put on hold as being "off-topic / can no longer be reproduced". A few minutes after it was put on hold, through sheer luck, I managed to figure out what was causing the strange behavior. I updated the question with steps to reproduce and waited for the question to go through the reopen queue.

It's been over 5 days and the question is now marked closed. I've edited a couple more times trying to improve the question but the reopen vote count has actually gone down from 4 to 2 over the last few days.

Is my question truly off topic? Am I misunderstanding what "no longer reproducible" means?

Comment: How? ... I think VTRO can't be retracted, and it takes 7~14 days for VTRO to expire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has now been reopened. Only the first edit counts to put it in the reopen queue. So it's much harder and slower if that first edit is unsuccessful. You're then relying on people clicking reopen because of the post bump, even on meta where many high rep users congregate and where there are no real specialist subjects that's not easy or quick.

It was your final edit that was [required to get the question reopened](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/368188/timeline). Your penultimate attempt only just failed by a 3-2 vote.

If you're going to edit your question, make sure that edit really does address the closure reason clearly I guess.

Comment: The [first edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/368188/timeline#history_24db5da9-a03c-4f90-bdf6-f30ddfe90145) after the question was closed added instructions to reproduce the behavior. All subsequent edits were just attempts to display that information in an easier to digest manner. With that in mind, I'm not really sure why it failed the reopen vote 3/2.

Comment: Sometimes things happen one way, sometimes the other. I try not to dwell too much on such things, it helps :)

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic If you'd taken more time to research the problem before asking your question, the final version could have been the first version and you wouldn't be asking this question at all.

Comment: @RobertLongson I guess I made a mistake. Sometimes people experiencing a bug on stack overflow don't know what is causing it, other times reviewers vote to leave closed without actually reading the changes made to the question. Such is life ;)