# Has tag editing been removed?

Tags: bug, tags, tag-wiki

I noticed this today.  Looking at a tag's info, the edit button is no longer  there.  Only history and excerpt history.

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have [5 pending suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7852833/tk421?tab=activity&sort=suggestions); you cannot submit more edits until the 5 pending edits are reviewed (see [Rate limit suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210416/336144) for more information).

It would seem that the button just disappears in this case (whereas on posts, an error message appears telling you why). I'm unsure if that's intended behaviour, but the pending edits explains why the button doesn't appear. It certainly isn't a particularly friendly part of the interface.

Comment: Thanks.  Before, I remember seeing an error message.

Comment: [Here is a related issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368188/9614249) that I made a meta post about a while ago.